# Get boolean indicating which route is active [Angular 2]

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I have an app.component.ts component which template contains several tab components, each one containing a particular link:

app.component.html:

```html
<h1>Tabs container</h1>
<div>
    <nav>
        <tab *ngFor="let tab of tabList" [name]="tab.name" [link]="tab.link" (eventEmitter)="closeTabEvent($event)"></tab>
    </nav>    
</div>
<div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

The HTML template of the tab component is tab.component.html:

```html
<a [routerLink]='link'  routerLinkActive="router-link-active">{{name}}</a>
<button *ngIf="tabIndex > 0" (click)="closeTab('tabToCloseKey')">Close tab</button>
```

I'm looking for a way to get a boolean value inside my TabComponent class, indicating which route is active.

Here is my TabComponent class:

```js
export class TabComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() name: string;
    @Input() link: string;
    @Input() param: string;
    targetArray: Array<any>;
    @Output() eventEmitter = new EventEmitter<[number, boolean]>();
    // @Output() isActiveEmitter = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
    static lastTabIndex: number = 0;
    tabIndex: number = 0;
    isActive: boolean = true;
    // @ViewChild('routerLinkActive') a;
    // el: HTMLElement;
    // className: string;

    constructor(private router: Router, private sharedService: SharedService, private _elRef: ElementRef) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        // this.className = this._elRef.nativeElement.find('a').className;
        // this.className = this.el.className;
        this.tabIndex = TabComponent.lastTabIndex;
        // console.log(this.className);
        TabComponent.lastTabIndex++;        
    }

    closeTab(){
        console.log('tab closed at index: ' + this.tabIndex);
        let tuple: [number, boolean];
        tuple = [this.tabIndex, this.isActive];
        this.eventEmitter.emit(tuple);
        this.hideTabComponent();
    }

    hideTabComponent(){
        console.log('Hiding component');
    }
}
```

I would to store the information indicating if the route corresponding to the tab is active or not in the isActive boolean attribute of this typescript class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use route param in the routerLink in the tab link so that you can catch that value in the Class with ActivatedRoute  as mentioned in the [Angular doc:](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html)